# Can I roast poached peanuts?

Tags: roasting, peanuts

Accidentally bought a bag is poached peanuts instead of roasted.  Can I roast them despite the fact that they are already cooked (and not raw)?  If so, are there any extra steps I should take in doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, just like you would for raw peanuts. However the boiled/poached peanuts have a bitter taste that is not removed by roasting and is generally unpleasant to eat as a snack. I would use these peanuts to make peanut sauces such as satay sauce, and possibly in other dishes where the peanuts are not the dominant flavor.

Comment: Some boiled peanuts taste less bitter than others, which I think is due to peanut variety.